# Magento - direct link to add product to cart with control mechanism

Tags: magento

Is there any chance to check if product is already in cart if is used direct link to add product do cart? For example, we send to customer link, he/she click on it one time and than by mystake click again. Result is, that in cart is 2 times more pieces.

We use one product option, text field, which is unique (in this example - options[8]=AX587AD9) for each order/customer, maybe there is a way to check it by this via API.

We can also use any mechanim to check it before Magento frontend, and then redirect to cart or use link to add product to cart...

Example of direct link:
http://www.example.com/checkout/cart/add?product=161&qty=1&options[8]=AX587AD9

Thanks for every suggestion,
Igor

Answer (score 1):

You can check if product is in cart or not using event observer.

You can use `checkout_cart_product_add_before` event to check if this product is already in your cart. your config file is look like this

```
<config>
...
<frontend>
    ...
    <events>
        <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
            <observers>
                <unique_event_name>
                    <class>{{modulename}}/observer</class>
                    <method>CheckItem</method>
                </unique_event_name>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
    </events>
    ...
</frontend>
...
```

And in your observer check your logic if something is in cart or not

```
 class <namespace>_<modulename>_Model_Observer
{

        public function CheckItem(Varien_Event_Observer $obs)
        {
            // Get the quote item
            $item = $obs->getQuoteItem();
            //and put your logic here
            // condition matched then redirect back customer with some message

        }



    }
```

Comment: Hi Muffadal

Thank you very much for help. I´m quite new to Magento , I hope I´ll be able to do it :D

Thank you again for help.

Regards from Slovakia,
Igor